# Вернуть массив из встроенной библиотеке на C++

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, marshal

Написал программу, в которой необходимо передать данные в библиотеку на C++ и вернуть какой-то массив в результате. В итоге выводит ошибку `Невозможно упаковать return value. Недопустимое сочетание управляемого и неуправляемого типов`. Я заранее не знаю, какой размер у массива результирующего будет, поэтому заранее память выделить не могу.

Мой код :
На C#

```
[DllImport("CppDll")]
public static extern ResultOfStrategy[] MyCppFunc(int countO, Data[] dataO, int countF, Data[] dataF);
var res = MyCppFunc(OptData.Count, OptData.ToArray(), FrwdData.Count, FrwdData.ToArray());
```

На C++

```
extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) ResultOfStrategy * WINAPI MyCppFunc(int countO, MYDATA * dataO, int countF, MYDATA * dataF)
{
return Optimization(countO, dataO, countF, dataF);
}
```

Код сам работает, если возвращать `bool`.

P.s. в файле C# и C++ созданы одинаковые структуры MYDATA(C++), Data(C#). 
Мы должны из библиотеки C++ вернуть массив структуры ResultOfStrategy, она представляет собой следующие поля

```
struct ResultOfStrategy
{
bool isGood;
double allProfit;
double CAGR;
double DD;
int countDeals;
double allProfitF;
double CAGRF;
double DDF;
int countDealsF;
Param Fast;
Param Slow;
Param Stop;
Param Tp;
newStop stloss;
};
```

Также, возможно, необходимо будет добавить еще переменную `ref`, которую мы будем инициализировать в библиотеке размером нашего выходного массива.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/marshaling-different-types-of-arrays

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/interop/marshaling-different-types-of-arrays

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/default-marshaling-for-arrays

Comment: И ещё много разных ссылок.

Comment: @JaponDemon спасибо, я гуглил не через маршалинг, сейчас попробую поискать)

Comment: @JaponDemon не нахожу я всё равно решения, там везде const size of array. А у меня в функции dll неизвестно, какой будет размер

Comment: Похоже, простого способа нет. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21798986/5045688), [2](https://basildoncoder.com/blog/marshalling-variable-length-array-from.html).

Comment: У вас присутствует признак окончания массива? Что такое `ResultOfStrategy`? Что такое `MYDATA`? Опишите подробнее, что бы можно было дать вам ординальный ответ на ваш вопрос. На данный момент не понятно ничего, особенно `вернуть какой-то массив`.

Comment: @Yami хорошо, распишу сейчас.

Answer (score -1):

Была похожая ситуация, представляю функцию **processFrame**, она использовалась для обработки кадра видео потока нейронной сетью, для нахождения объектов. Для вашей проблемы стоит обратить внимание на параметры:

- *OUT* *NOTRELEASE* float*& outData
- *OUT* int* numBoxes

Первый параметр, указатель на массив дробных чисел, память для него выделялась на стороне библиотеки, а numBoxes его размер.

```
void processFrame(_IN_ unsigned char* frame, int count, _OUT_ int* resaultStatus, _OUT_ _NOTRELEASE_ float*& outData, _OUT_ int* numBoxes, _OUT_ int*otherDim, int resizeX = -1, int resizeY = -1);
```

Так же привожу обертку функции в C# коде.

```
[DllImport(DLL_NAME, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void processFrame(IntPtr frame, int count, ref int resaultStatus, ref IntPtr outData,
                ref int numBoxes, ref int otherDim, int resizeX = -1, int resizeY = -1);
```

Если будет интересно, что за параметры IN и OUT, то это пустые дефайны, оставленные коллегой для наглядности.

```
#define _OUT_ /*выходные параметры метода*/
#define _IN_ /*входные параметры метода*/
#define _NOTRELEASE_ /*используется для запрета освобождения памяти */
```